# Error in JavaScript array length

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error: Cannot read property 'length'

```
var spritearray = [];

spritearray[0] = {"name": "North", "lat":0, "lon": 10};

spritearray[1] = {"name": "south", "lat":0, "lon": 20};

for (var i= 0; i< spritearray.length; i++)
{

    var Ncardinal = spritearray[i];
    sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);
}
```

Comment: the given code is fine - your error must either come from somewhere else or you omitted some crucial part here.

Comment: Perhaps from the `labelBox` function()?. Can you please post that code too?

Comment: @ David  R  function labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, domElement)
    {
  this.screenVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  this.position = convertlatlonToVec3(Ncardinal.lat,Ncardinal.lon).multiplyScalar(radius);
  this.box = document.createElement('div');
  a = document.createElement('a');
  a.innerHTML = Ncardinal.name;
  a.href ='http://www.google.de';
  this.box.className = "spritelabel";
  this.box.appendChild(a);
  
  this.domElement = domElement;
  this.domElement.appendChild(this.box);
 }

Comment: don't put code in a comment, unless it's one line or shorter. Also, the problem isn't in that function. Can you find exactly where and how you are getting the problem? Your example does not recreate it.

Comment: i got the answer,but i dont know how to explain it.
i had written var spritearray[] outside the function.
when i wrote inside the function its working properly. thanks for helping me.